# Existence of uniqur inner product on $V$

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space with basis $X$. Then show that there is a unique inner product on $V$ with respect to which $X$ is an orthonormal basis.
please help me how could I construct such inner product.

Comment: You give its values on $X$, and then extend it to $V$ by linearity.

Comment: Hint: define it using coordinates in terms of $X$. Then, the coordinate vectors of vectors in $X$ are the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{\operatorname{dim} V}$. There's already a well-known inner product that makes them orthogonal!

Comment: I cant understand.  Please write down explicitly sir.@Gerry Myerson

Comment: What I wrote was quite explicit. Look: let your orthonormal basis be $X=\{\,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r\,\}$. What can you say about the inner product of $x_i$ and $x_j$? [If you can't answer that, you had better look up the meaning of "orthonormal".]

Comment: yeah sir I get it. Thank u @Gerry Myerson

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.